# Узнать имя jar файла, в котором запускатеся код

Tags: java

есть jar файл w1.jar, нужно вывести в консоль его имя, имя файла может менятся, поэтому нужен код, который определит название

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В любом из методов класса, содержащего `main`

```
String jarName = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain()
                                    .getCodeSource()
                                    .getLocation()
                                    .toURI()).getName();
```

Или вместо `getClass()` можно написать конкретный класс, содержащий `main`.

Comment: выдает ошибку на getClass() тип сделайте объктом его

Comment: По такому описанию ошибки что-то внятное посоветовать вам невозможно.

Comment: в эклипсе подчеркивается красным и лампочка с крестиком

Comment: Если вы этот код пытаетесь выполнить в статическом методе, то как я уже писал в ответе, замените `getClass()` на `ИмяВашегоКласса.class`

Comment: спасибо, просто про фитчу с `ИмяВашегоКласса.class` я не знал, я думал что просто имя класса нужно без `.class`